# Launch fullscreen browser with specified URI in Android

Tags: android, browser, fullscreen, boot

I have android-stick with HDMI connector that plug into TV.

I need to launch browser (no matter which one) and navigate to my URL, in full-screen mode.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
//call this methord before setContentview() this will make screen full

public static void fullscreen(Activity koutuk)
    {
        try {
            koutuk.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            koutuk.getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                koutuk.getWindow().setFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

/// then find id to top most parent view of layout ie relative/linear

View v = findViewById(R.id.linear);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);

now load your Webview from Activity oncreate
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to achieve that without any code

Comment: :) predefine tags are available but i am not aware of that sorry